# como poner un mensaje en mi javascript para que no me deje insertar campos en blanco

Tags: php, javascript

espero se encuentren muy bien.

como puedo agregarle a mi formulario javascript una condición que arroje un mensaje si el usuario intenta registrar sin datos el formulario?

este es mi formulario y javascript que uso:
Javascript

```
<script>
// nuevo método para eliminar la fila, recibe como parámetro el botón presionado 
// y navega hasta el nodo de la fila para eliminarla

 function eliminarFilatre(boton){
 // navegar hasta el nodo fila
 fila = boton.parentNode.parentNode;
 // navegar al nodo superior de la fila y borrar la fila
 fila.parentNode.removeChild(fila);


}
    function guardar(){

        var _posatendi = document.getElementById("posatendi").value;
        var _tipotrabajo = document.getElementById("tipotrabajo").value;
        var _horainicio = document.getElementById("horainicio").value;

        var fila="<tr><td>"+
            "<input type='text' class='camptwo' style='width:60px;' name='posatendi[]' value='"+_posatendi+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>"+
            "<input type='text' class='camptwo' style='width:150px;' name='tipotrabajo[]' value='"+_tipotrabajo+"' readonly>"+
            "</td><td>" +
            "<input type='time' class='camptwo' style='width:98px;' name='horainicio[]' value='"+_horainicio+"' readonly>"+
            "</td></tr>" +          

 // botón que llama al método eliminar fila y pasa como parámetro
 // el botón
"<td><button onclick='eliminarFilatre(this)' class='md-close'>-</button></td>" ;

        var btn = document.createElement("TR");
        btn.innerHTML=fila;
        document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
    }

</script>
```

PHP

```
<h2>Insertar registros</h2>

                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>DATO1</th>
                                    <th>DATO2</th>
                                    <th>DATO3</th>

                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
    <th scope="row">
    <select id="posatendi" required>
    <option></option>    
    <option value="1">1</option>    
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select></th>
<?php
   $sql8 = "SELECT id_trabajo,nom_trabajo FROM para_trabajos";
   $result8=mysqli_query($conn,$sql8);
?>                                   
    <td>
    <select id="tipotrabajo" required>
    <option></option>    
<?php

    while ($row8 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result8))
    {
    ?>  
        <option value="<?=$row8['nom_trabajo']?>"><?=$row8['nom_trabajo']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>

                                    <td><input type="time" id="horainicio"></td>


                                </tr>                           

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
<br>
<button onclick="guardar()">+</button>


<form action="registrar.php" method="POST">
    <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tablita">

            </tbody>
        </table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Registrar" />           
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se me ocurren dos opciones, una seria igualando a una cadena vacias y otra comprobando su longitud
Comprobación con cadena

```
if(_posatendi == ""){
  return false
}else{
  return true
}
```

Comprobación con longitud

```
if(_posatendi.length == 0){
  return false
}else{
  return true
}
```

También puedes poner en el formulario que lo compruebe antes, en caso de ser verdadero mandaría el formulario, sería de la siguiente manera

```js
function validarFormulario() {
  var _posatendi = document.getElementById("posatendi").value;

  if (_posatendi.length == 0 || _posatendi == "") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Esto lo añadirías de la siguiente forma

```
<form method="" action="" onsubmit="return validarFormulario()">`
```

Comment: estupendo tu ejemplo me funciona perfecto era lo que necesitaba, muchisimas gracias.